# What does xsi mean when defining arguments

Tags: magento2, di

I've seen for a while now that inside the `arguments` tag in di.xml or in the layout files the attribute `xsi:type` is used.
I took it for granted and used it like that, but I don't understand why the need for the `xsi` namespace. What does it mean?
The `name` attribute does not have a namespace.

Here is a random example.

```
 <arguments>
    <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="default_message_identifier" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\EscapeRenderer::CODE</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```

I know what the value of the `xsi:type` attribute means, but not why the need for the namespace.
This is not impeding my work, but it bugs me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Magento dev team wants to use the `attribute` named `type` which is deferred from XML Shema Interface. That's why they use `xsi:type="blablabla"`, not `type="blablabla"`. I don't find they declare an `attribute` named `type`. So, if you change the `xsi:type="blablabla"` to `type="blablabla"`, the XML validation will throws an error.

Here is an example of default `catalog_product_view.xml` XML: [catalog_product_view.xml](https://gist.github.com/rendyep/b2d957b04ddbb4c3f8bc16c2a959aaf3)

I have reconstructed the XML Schema Definition based on `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` path of the XML itself: [page_configuration.xsd](https://gist.github.com/rendyep/5bf2aab5b3f30b7bca7d35d8fcad171e)

You won't see any definition of `type` attribute in element named `argument`. Therefore, if you use `<argument type="string">`, the XML becomes invalid.

You may try the validation result of those XML and XSD here: W3C XML Schema (XSD) Validation online. Try to change the thing you asked, let's say, `<argument xsi:type="string">` to `<argument type="string">` and validate the XML, you'll see an error.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I knew that. But my question is "why is that needed? couldn't just be `type` and that's it?"

Comment: I have updated the answer and attached an example of page layout XML, and reconstructed the XML Schema Definition of it based on tag ` xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.